# SO is not formatting Java code correctly

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

Have a look at the last block of code in this question:

[Sieve of Eratosthenes in Java: A Puzzle and some optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155807/sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-java-a-problem-and-some-optimization)

(The block right below "Thanks for all the feedback")

What's going wrong? I've wrapped the code in `<code>` tags, but it won't display properly.

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use tags/HTML markup, use [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) instead. Tag behaviors are "broken" on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Define "properly"? I changed it to use the space-indentation approach (ctrl+k) rather than `<code>`, which *might* help - but note that the spacing might be off as it is using tabs (spaces tend to work better, IIRC).